# Java : Interactive Console using jTextArea

Tags: java, ide, console, cmd, command

I am developing a cmd like console using jTextArea, for an IDE. What I want to do is as I click the execute button, it provides me interactive input/output screen in the jTextArea.

I am able to grab the output contents of the cmd screen, but what if user wants to run a command like take two integers as input from stdin (here from my jTextArea) and display the sum, on my console screen, as if it happened in a normal cmd/terminal.

How do I send input to that instance/session?

Answer (score 1):

See [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), method [java.lang.Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29)

The name `OutputStream` is a doubtful choice because it's the input of the underlying process, the output for your program.

Comment: I see you answered noobie-programmer's question correctly, and then he deleted it. Good show on your part, but not on his.

Comment: I don't understand: what post?

Comment: pages you make me refer to seem to be fine.
can u plz help chose me exactly which method/s i need to use for my task?

Comment: No, You have to search a little to becomes a master of code ;-) Usually, I take money to work.

Comment: Sorry, a post made at about the same time as this one, where he added an ActionListener twice to the same JButton (the leftButton I think). I missed that. 1+ to your answer here by the way.

Comment: Thanks, you're very easy with SO interface!